How to use custom CAChain in self-hosted gitlab instance?
I have my own self-hosted gitlab instance that is on the private 10.1.x.y/16 network, where it is signed by corporate.  I cannot seem to locate how I can define the custom chains/pem so I can utilise the certificate/key pair.
Thanks,

Para utilizar un CAChain personalizado en una instancia de GitLab autohospedada, sigue estos pasos:
Preparar el CAChain:
Asegúrate de tener tu archivo de CAChain (por ejemplo, ca-chain.crt) listo. Este archivo debe contener todos los certificados intermedios y el certificado raíz en el orden correcto.
Copiar el CAChain al servidor:
Sube el archivo ca-chain.crt al servidor donde está alojado GitLab. Puedes usar scp o cualquier otro método de transferencia de archivos.
Configurar GitLab para usar el CAChain:
Abre el archivo de configuración de GitLab, generalmente ubicado en /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb.
Añade o modifica la siguiente línea para apuntar a tu archivo de CAChain:
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/path/to/your/ca-chain.crt"
Si también necesitas configurar el certificado y la clave privada, asegúrate de incluir las siguientes líneas:
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/path/to/your/private.key"
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/path/to/your/certificate.crt"
Reconfigurar GitLab:
Después de realizar los cambios en el archivo de configuración, ejecuta el siguiente comando para aplicar los cambios:
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
Reiniciar GitLab:
Finalmente, reinicia GitLab para asegurarte de que los cambios se apliquen correctamente:
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
Siguiendo estos pasos, tu instancia de GitLab debería estar configurada para utilizar tu CAChain personalizado. Si encuentras algún problema, revisa los logs de GitLab para obtener más detalles sobre posibles errores.

I appreciate the quick answer.  I will try this when cleared with the needed downtime in case it fails.
